# Safari Push Notification with Windows Azure

Tags: azure, safari, azure-mobile-services, safari-push-notifications

I'm trying to use [Safari Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1) with Windows Azure as backend. I was able to upload `Website Push ID: web.com...` certificate to Azure `Mobile Services` and it was accepted without any error message in the `apple push notification settings`.

To handle the Web Service Endpoints (`webServiceURL/version/pushPackages/websitePushID`, `webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceToken/registrations/websitePushID`, and so on) I created in the Mobile Services a API which is all working fine.

But I'm unable to send a push notification or get an error message.

My test code looks like this:

```
function send(req, res) {
    var push = req.service.push;
    var devicesTable = req.service.tables.getTable('devices');
    devicesTable.read({
        success: function(devices) {
            devices.forEach(function(device) {

                console.log("send to deviceToken " + device.deviceToken);

                push.apns.send(device.deviceToken, {
                    alert: 'Toast: A new Mobile Services task.',
                    payload: {
                        inAppMessage: "Hey, a new item arrived: '"
                    }
                });

                push.apns.send(device.deviceToken, {
                        alert: {
                            "title": "Test 123 ",
                            "body": "Test 123 ",
                            "action": "View"
                        },
                        "url-args": ["boarding"]
                    },
                    {
                        error : function(err) {
                            console.log("send error " + err);
                        }
                    }
                );

            });
        }
    });

    res.send(200, "");
}
```

Is my problem the [formatting of the dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW12) or does Azure Mobile Services for some reason not support Safari Push Notification?

As far as I know the APNS is the same for iOS, Mac and Safari push notifications.

**Update:** I tested it with [SimplePush](https://github.com/jPaolantonio/SimplePush/blob/master/simplepush.php) so the certificate is fine as is the registration of Safari. My payload looks like this:

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => array(
        'title' => 'test',
        'body' => $message
    ),
    'url-args'  => array('test'),
);
```

Comment: I notice that your first push.apns.send doesn't have a error handler - maybe add one there to see if you're getting anything back.  Also see if you get anything specific back by using apns.getFeedback().  See examples on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj839711.aspx

Comment: I tried both, no error message at all.

Comment: Simplify the message format you're sending to see if it's something in the message that is causing non-delivery.  Is your device token valid as held in the table? They can change through OS upgrades as well.

Comment: The device token is valid, as I wrote it works with SimplePush. I also tested with the most simplified message format possible: title and body are required. url-args are required as well when there is a placeholder(s) used in urlFormatString.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you've correctly registered your Safari client as per the guidance from Apple - have you tested your client using on a non-Azure implementation?  Looking at the implementation guide from Apple there seems to be a lot of moving pieces even when not considering Azure as your push info source.

Comment: Yes, I tested with a non-Auzre implementation.